# getLifecycle().getState() is still CREATED after onStart()

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I'm invoking some callbacks on my Activity which functionality is dependent on the state of the Application and Activity and get called when the app is foregrounded and backgrounded.  I'm also logging my activity lifecycle method calls.  Per the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle), once `onStart()` is called, `getCurrentState()` should be `STARTED`, but I'm seeing that it's always `CREATED` and I don't know why.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s onCreate()", getClass().getName()));

    //... more code
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s onStart()", getClass().getName()));

    //... more code
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s onSaveInstanceState()", getClass().getName()));

    //... more code
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s onResume()", getClass().getName()));

    //... more code
}

@Override
public onAppBackgrounded() {
    String class = getClass().getName();
    Lifecycle.State state = getLifecycle().getCurrentState();
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s onAppBackgrounded() - %s", class, state);

    //... more code
}

@Override
public onAppForegrounded() {
    String class = getClass().getName();
    Lifecycle.State state = getLifecycle().getCurrentState();
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s onAppForegrounded() - %s", class, state);

    //... more code
}
```

`onAppBackgrounded()`, and `onAppForegrounded()` are just callback methods that are registered with a `LifecycleObserver` that is observing the Application Lifecycle.

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
fun onLifecycleEventStart() {
    callbackRegistrar.onApplicationForegrounded()
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
fun onLifecycleEventStop() {
    callbackRegistrar.onApplicationBackgrounded()
}
```

Here is what I'm seeing when I foreground my app:

2019-07-22 17:51:

```
19.070 4754-4754/com.myapp D/TAG: com.myapp.MyActivity onCreate()
2019-07-22 17:51:19.989 4754-4754/com.myapp D/TAG: com.myapp.MyActivity onStart()
2019-07-22 17:51:19.990 4754-4754/com.myapp D/TAG: com.myapp.MyActivity onApplicationForegrounded() - CREATED
2019-07-22 17:51:20.013 4754-4754/com.myapp D/TAG: com.myapp.MyActivity onResume()
```

Here is what I'm seeing when I background my app:

2019-07-22 1

```
8:05:02.527 4754-4754/com.myapp D/TAG: com.myapp.MyActivity onPause()
2019-07-22 18:05:02.664 4754-4754/com.myapp D/TAG: com.myapp.MyActivity onStop()
2019-07-22 18:05:02.703 4754-4754/com.myapp D/TAG: com.myapp.MyActivity onSavedInstanceState()
2019-07-22 18:05:03.229 4754-4754/com.myapp D/TAG: com.myapp.MyActivity onApplicationBackgrounded() - CREATED
```

And, when I have more than 1 activity registered with the state change listener, they all are in the `CREATED` state.  Not really sure what I'm missing.  The docs say that it does that if onSavedInstanceState() is called before onStop(), but thats clearly not happening here.

Ideally I'd like to use getLifecycle().getState() to tell which activity is in the foreground when the application is backgrounded and foregrounded.

Comment: The docs state that `onSaveInstanceState()` is always called before the `ON_STOP` lifecycle event (which is absolutely different from `onStop()` of an Activity, which has no such ordering guarantee).

Answer (score 0):

Its happens because of activity life cycle. In activity life cycle **onStop()** should go **onCreate()** for following cases

> Once your activity is stopped, the system might destroy the process
> that contains the activity if the system needs to recover memory.
> Even if the system destroys the process while the activity is stopped, the system still retains the state of the View objects (such as text in an EditText widget) in a Bundle (a blob of key-value pairs) and restores them if the user navigates back to the activity.

for more details refer [Activity Life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Refer the lifecycle diagram on the same page